# VHDL schematic without connections

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, vivado

I'm learning VHDL and I tried to replicate a circuit that I found surfing in internet. The problem is that the schematic shows without connections in the input ports.

The program is a frequency divider that drives an LED depending on the selection of a MUX.

I'm using Vivado software, the board is the Digilent Arty S7

[image: Input Ports don't have connection to the circuit]

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity LED_blink_freq is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           EN : in STD_LOGIC;
           SW1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           SW2 : in STD_LOGIC;
           LED_OUT : out STD_LOGIC);
end LED_blink_freq;

architecture arq_LED_blink_freq of LED_blink_freq is

constant cnt_100hz: natural := 500000;
constant cnt_50hz: natural := 1000000;
constant cnt_10hz: natural := 5000000;
constant cnt_1hz: natural := 50000000;


signal s_cnt_100hz: natural range 0 to cnt_100hz;
signal s_cnt_50hz: natural range 0 to cnt_50hz;
signal s_cnt_10hz: natural range 0 to cnt_10hz;
signal s_cnt_1hz: natural range 0 to cnt_1hz;



signal TOGGLE_100HZ : std_logic := '0';
signal TOGGLE_50HZ  : std_logic := '0';
signal TOGGLE_10HZ  : std_logic := '0';
signal TOGGLE_1HZ   : std_logic := '0';

signal LED_SELECT : std_logic;

begin

p_100hz: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if s_cnt_100hz = cnt_100hz - 1 then
           TOGGLE_100hz <= not TOGGLE_100hz;
           s_cnt_100hz <= 0;
        else
            s_cnt_100hz <= s_cnt_100hz + 1;
        end if;
     end if;                                                                                                                                           
end process p_100hz;

p_50hz: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if s_cnt_50hz = cnt_50hz - 1 then
           TOGGLE_50hz <= not TOGGLE_50hz;
           s_cnt_50hz <= 0;
        else
            s_cnt_50hz <= s_cnt_50hz + 1;
        end if;
     end if;                                                                                                                                           
end process p_50hz;

p_10hz: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if s_cnt_10hz = cnt_10hz - 1 then
           TOGGLE_10hz <= not TOGGLE_10hz;
           s_cnt_100hz <= 0;
        else
            s_cnt_10hz <= s_cnt_10hz + 1;
        end if;
     end if;                                                                                                                                           
end process p_10hz;

p_1hz: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if s_cnt_1hz = cnt_1hz - 1 then
           TOGGLE_1hz <= not TOGGLE_1hz;
           s_cnt_1hz <= 0;
        else
            s_cnt_1hz <= s_cnt_1hz + 1;
        end if;
     end if;                                                                                                                                           
end process p_1hz;

--MUX
LED_OUT <= TOGGLE_100hz when (SW1 = '0' and SW2 = '0') else
           TOGGLE_50hz  when (SW1 = '0' and SW2 = '1') else
           TOGGLE_10hz  when (SW1 = '1' and SW2 = '0') else
           TOGGLE_1hz;

          
LED_OUT <= LED_SELECT and EN;

end arq_LED_blink_freq;
```

I leave the original code in the following link:

https://nandland.com/your-first-vhdl-program-an-led-blinker/

Comment: Why is LED_OUT driven in two different places in your code?  You didn't replicate the code very well.  Have you tried the original code and then your code?  Looks like the first LED_OUT assignment is supposed to be LED_SELECT in your code.

Comment: I see it. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your typo in the mux, the signal `LED_SELECT` never changes from its initial value, and so the result of the AND is always '0'. The resulting schematic shows exactly that.

Replace `LED_SELECT` by `LED_OUT` in the mux.